# Rails 6: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: relation "users" does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am trying to migrate my migration in Rails 6 but then I am having this error:

```
== 20200610041443 AddDeviseToUsers: migrating =================================
-- change_table(:users)
rails aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist
/Users/jumong/Desktop/Overtime/db/migrate/20200610041443_add_devise_to_users.rb:7:in `block in up'
/Users/jumong/Desktop/Overtime/db/migrate/20200610041443_add_devise_to_users.rb:5:in `up'
/Users/jumong/Desktop/Overtime/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/jumong/Desktop/Overtime/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:3:in `load'
bin/rails:3:in `<main>'

Caused by:
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist
/Users/jumong/Desktop/Overtime/db/migrate/20200610041443_add_devise_to_users.rb:7:in `block in up'
/Users/jumong/Desktop/Overtime/db/migrate/20200610041443_add_devise_to_users.rb:5:in `up'
/Users/jumong/Desktop/Overtime/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/jumong/Desktop/Overtime/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:3:in `load'
bin/rails:3:in `<main>'

Caused by:
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist
/Users/jumong/Desktop/Overtime/db/migrate/20200610041443_add_devise_to_users.rb:7:in `block in up'
/Users/jumong/Desktop/Overtime/db/migrate/20200610041443_add_devise_to_users.rb:5:in `up'
/Users/jumong/Desktop/Overtime/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/jumong/Desktop/Overtime/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:3:in `load'
bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

So far here's my migration file:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

class AddDeviseToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def self.up
    change_table :users do |t|
      ## Database authenticatable
      t.string :email,              null: false, default: ""
      t.string :encrypted_password, null: false, default: ""

      ## Recoverable
      t.string   :reset_password_token
      t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at

      ## Rememberable
      t.datetime :remember_created_at

      ## Trackable
      # t.integer  :sign_in_count, default: 0, null: false
      # t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
      # t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
      # t.inet     :current_sign_in_ip
      # t.inet     :last_sign_in_ip

      ## Confirmable
      # t.string   :confirmation_token
      # t.datetime :confirmed_at
      # t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
      # t.string   :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable

      ## Lockable
      # t.integer  :failed_attempts, default: 0, null: false # Only if lock strategy is :failed_attempts
      # t.string   :unlock_token # Only if unlock strategy is :email or :both
      # t.datetime :locked_at

      t.string :first_name
      t.string :last_name
      t.string :type

      # Uncomment below if timestamps were not included in your original model.
      # t.timestamps null: false
    end

    add_index :users, :email,                unique: true
    add_index :users, :reset_password_token, unique: true
    # add_index :users, :confirmation_token,   unique: true
    # add_index :users, :unlock_token,         unique: true
  end

  def self.down
    # By default, we don't want to make any assumption about how to roll back a migration when your
    # model already existed. Please edit below which fields you would like to remove in this migration.
    raise ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration
  end
end
```

And here's my schema:

```
# This file is auto-generated from the current state of the database. Instead
# of editing this file, please use the migrations feature of Active Record to
# incrementally modify your database, and then regenerate this schema definition.
#
# This file is the source Rails uses to define your schema when running `rails
# db:schema:load`. When creating a new database, `rails db:schema:load` tends to
# be faster and is potentially less error prone than running all of your
# migrations from scratch. Old migrations may fail to apply correctly if those
# migrations use external dependencies or application code.
#
# It's strongly recommended that you check this file into your version control system.

ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 0) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

end
```

I already tried running `rake db:reset` and `rake db:drop db:create db:migrate db:seed` but I am still having the same error. I even doubled check my migrations but still no luck on solving this issue.

Can anybody help me please? I am beginner?

Comment: Do you already have a users table (with its corresponding migration file)?

Comment: It was never created when I run `rails db:migrate` it automatically gave me those errors.

Comment: But did you create the file? I ask because the devise generator will use `create_table` or `change_table` depending if you already have a users table.

Comment: did you mean running this? `rails g devise User first_name last_name type:string` if so yes.

Comment: Running that created the devise User model but did not migrate them to schema file.

Comment: No, not that. Anyway, try replacing `change_table` with `create_table` in `db/migrate/20200610041443_add_devise_to_users.rb`.

Comment: It says `NameError: uninitialized constant User`

Answer (score 0):

I created a devise migration from scratch and there are some differences between it and your migration file. The new migration starts like this:

```
class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
```

There is no `self.up` and `self.down`. Try to make these changes, it may help.

Comment: `self.up` and `self.down` were using in older versions of rails, but they are still supported

Comment: Oh, I see. I was supposed to comment in the original question but I still don't have enough reputation. Thanks for the info.